# Jetpack Compose collectAsState issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Composes collectAsState() function to collect from this StateFlow

```
val _authToken = MutableStateFlow(AuthToken("", 0))
val authToken: StateFlow<AuthToken> = _authToken
val authToken by loginViewModel.authToken.collectAsState() // this returns AuthToken which is fine.
```

However, when turning a cold flow into a stateflow using the stateIn operator then using collectAsState() it returns a State version of the object which is odd then I need to call .value on collectAsState() to retrieve it.

Does anyone know why this happens?

```
val user = repository.getUser(viewModelScope).stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), null)
val user = profileViewModel.user.collectAsState() // returns State<User>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```kotlin
val user = profileViewModel.user.collectAsState()
```

With

```kotlin
val user by profileViewModel.user.collectAsState()
```

Answer (score 5):

Well it IS supposed to return State. Compose offers the delegate syntax to allow you to treat state as raw types.

If you want to extract the data from `State`, you make use of the `by` keyword. For example,

`var a : T by b : State<T>`
and,
`var a : State<T> = b : State<T>`

In your case, if you want `user` to be of type `User` and not `State<User>`, you should change the initialisation to

`val user by profileViewModel.user.collectAsState() // returns User`

Also, you should have known from the name of the method, it is collectAs`State`.

Answer (score 1):

With the new version for `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-*:2.6.0-alpha01`, use `collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` instead